# asp.net mvc select list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ok what i want to do is to using forcollection["Selectlist"] only selected things in the select list will be availabe when the form posted i am using add ,remove mechanism in my listbox , so i want to make everything that is there in the checkbox as available to the forcollection["Selectlist"]. can it be done?

Comment: It might be helpful if you clarify what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this might help you:

**jQuery DropDown Checkboxes**
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DropDownCheckboxes

Comment: What i want is that plain select list.every item posted of its posted to the server without selecting

Comment: Is that useful, if you don't have the ability to select specific ones?  If you are sending all of the items to the view, and you want to capture all of the items, *don't you already have those items* in your controller method, or in the database?

Comment: Well I have the items in the generic list and i am binding them from there  As i said i can add and remove already inserted items. so the list can completely change